# And operation and case insensitivity in awk regular expression?

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, awk, regular-expression

I'm trying to match filenames that contain two text patterns but the matching process should ignore case. Neither of the following regular expressions work:

Setting the awk variable 'IGNORECASE' to a nonzero value (as recommended in `info awk`) so that all regular expression and string operations ignore case, and then building a logical "and" operation using two regular expressions prints all files:

```
$ ls -R | awk 'IGNORECASE = 1;/bingo/ && /number/;'
```

---

I tried converting the data to lowercase before using lookaheads (I know the second lookahead is not needed) to match both the text patterns "bingo" and "number". However awk does not print any output which it should by default [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273625/289865), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/)

```
$ ls -R | awk 'tolower($0) ~ /(?=.*bingo)(?=.*number)/'
```

Which part of the awk or regular expression syntax is wrong (or what is missing) and what is the correct way to do a case-independent search that is only successful when the additional pattern appears on the same line?

#### Update:

from running

```
$ ls -R | awk '/bingo/'
```

it seems that `awk` may be performing the match against the lines in each file in the output of `ls -R` due to filenames not containing the string constant "bingo" being matched by `awk`. If this is the case, how do you get `awk` to have the same behavior as `grep` when receiving output from (i.e. sent through) a pipe?

Comment: `IGNORECASE` is only supported by GNU awk (`gawk`) -- so if you have that, use `gawk` instead of `awk`. Lookaheads/behinds are not supported by any awk implementation.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: If you're trying to recursively match filenames then perhaps `find . -iname '*bingo*' -iname '*number*'` would be more suitable?

Comment: @mosvy I was focused on getting the regular expression to work that I didn't consider that `awk` does not support lookaheads or lookbehinds, thanks. I tried replacing `awk` with `gawk` in the first code example but `gawk` still lists all files

Comment: @steeldriver good suggestion, does that perform an implicit "and" operation? Is it possible that `awk` is searching each file for the text pattern instead of searching the output from `ls` like `grep` does?

Comment: Of course it will, because gawk will treat `IGNORECASE=1` as a pattern, which will be always true (same as a simple `1;`). Use `gawk -vIGNORECASE=1 '/bingo/ && /number/'` or put the `IGNORECASE=1` assignment in a `BEGIN` block.

Comment: @mosvy `ls -R | awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} /bingo/ && /number/'` and `ls -R | awk -vIGNORECASE=1 /bingo/ && /number/'` both work, so it seems that regular `awk` also supports `IGNORECASE`. Do you know why your version i.e. `ls -R | gawk -vIGNORECASE=1 /foo/ || /bar/'` also prints filenames that do not contain foo or bar, e.g. baz.txt is also printed. May be you can turn your comment into question.

Comment: No, regular `awk` doesn't support it. It's probably that the `awk` on your system is actually `gawk` -- `awk --version` will tell you if that's the case. That cannot be assumed even on a per-distro basis -- on debian the user can change it with `update-alternatives --set awk /usr/bin/gawk`.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia (regarding `find`) yes it does: from `man find`: *Where an operator is missing, -a is assumed.* (`-a` being logical AND)

Comment: The `||` instead of `&&` was an error in a previous version of the comment, but even with `||`, `touch baz.txt; ls -R | gawk -vIGNORECASE=1 '/foo/ || /bar/'` will not print the `baz.txt` file.

Answer (score 5):

wrt your first script:

```
awk 'IGNORECASE = 1;/bingo/ && /number/;'
```

1. IGNORECASE is gawk-only as pointed out in the comments, and
2. your awk code is equivalent to:

   ```
   awk '(IGNORECASE = 1){print}; (/bingo/ && /number/){print}'
   ```

so it will do a case-insensitive match in GNU awk but not in other awks, and it will always print the current line (since the assignment `IGNORECASE=1` evaluates to `1` which is a true condition) and then any line containing both bingo and number will be printed a second time.

wrt your second script:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /(?=.*bingo)(?=.*number)/'
```

That `?=` stuff is PCRE lookarounds - awk supports EREs, not PCREs, so I'd have to think about what it'd really mean in an ERE but whatever it is, it's not what you wanted it to mean.

wrt your statement that:

> It seems that awk may be performing the match against the lines in each file in the output of ls -R

I don't know why you think that but no, it's not.

Here's what I think you want in GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}; /bingo/ && /number/'
```

Or:

```
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/bingo/ && /number/'
```

and in any awk:

```
awk '{lc=tolower($0)}; (lc ~ /bingo/) && (lc ~ /number/)'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find names in the current directory or below that contains the strings `bingo` and `number` in any case, you should not pass the output of `ls -R` through `awk` but instead use `find`:

```
find . -iname '*bingo*' -iname '*number*'
```

The `-iname` predicate is non-standard but commonly implemented and will match the filename currently being examined against the given globbing pattern case-insensitively.

If you would like to get the filename *only*, and not the complete pathname to the found files, then use

```
find . -iname '*bingo*' -iname '*number*' -exec basename {} \;
```

With GNU `find`, you could use

```
find . -iname '*bingo*' -iname '*number*' -printf '%f\n'
```

which will be quicker than using `basename`.

If you know that the order of the two words is "`bingo` followed by `number`", then use `-iname '*bingo*number*'` with `find` instead of two `-iname` tests.

If you know that this is the order of the words that you'd like to find, you may also use `bash` directly:

```bash
shopt -s globstar      # enable ** to match across / in pathnames
shopt -s nocaseglob    # enable case-insensitive globbing
shopt -s failglob      # error when a pattern does not match anything

printf '%s\n' **/*bingo*number*
```

To get the filename portion of the pathnames:

```bash
shopt -s globstar nocaseglob failglob

for name in **/*bingo*number*; do
    basename -- "$name"
done
```

or, if you have GNU `basename` and don't expect to ever match *thousands* of files,

```bash
shopt -s globstar nocaseglob failglob

basename -a -- **/*bingo*number*
```

where `-a` tells the utility to show the filename portion of each argument (multiple arguments).

Stéphane points out in comments that to ignore the order of the two substrings in e.g. `bash`, you could use the extended globbing pattern

```
!(!(*bingo*)|!(*number*))
```

This works by matching every name except names that *do not* contain either of the two strings.  So you'll get

```bash
shopt -s globstar nocaseglob failglob
shopt -s extglob  # for extended globbing patterns in bash

for name in **/!(!(*bingo*)|!(*number*)); do
    basename -- "$name"
done
```

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Comment: See also `!(!(*bingo*)|!(*number*))` in `ksh`/`bash -o extglob`. Or `@(*bingo*&*number*)` in ksh93, or `*bingo*~^*number*` in `zsh -o extendedglob`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas To ignore the order of the substrings, yes, and ouch.

Comment: See also [How to open or list all files whose name matches two patterns in Bash](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/287175)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the edits. Summer is not good for my brain it seems.